# EF/MS SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

There are multiple questions here and in google results regarding this error. But I can't find any situation with the simptoms I have.

So, my code constructs `DbContext` with connection string buildin from configuration file:

[image]

Any query fails with error specified in topic header:

[image]

I 100% know that I can connect to the server with such name using credentials specified in connection string:

[image]

More, I can communicate with the database using EF infrastructure. For example migrations via VS powershell:

[image]

This problem occured after I tried to add LocalDB support on another laptop that has no SQL Server installed.

What I have tried:

- obvious SQL Server process/VS/computer restart
- fixing connection factory in `app.config`
- reinstalling EF after deleting `app.config`
- hardcoding connection string with `SqlConnectionFactory`

But still I have no success. What I can do else?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find root of the problem but was able to fix this issue by removing Automigrating `DBContext` initializer and updating DB manually.
This is confusing a bit because before I had no problems with automigrations and initializer.